# nginx as proxy for wss

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

real address => https://wssserver1/wss/
Only test1 able to access, try using proxy_pass for other testX able to browse wssserver1.

When I open it from test2
https://test1/wssserver1, it manage to update the header name but nothing appear.
error log show it direct wss path to localhost instead of wssserver1
/var/www/html/wss/ is not found.

My nginx config

test 1 nginx config

```
location /wssserver1 {
  proxy_buffers 8 32k;
  proxy_buffer_size 64k;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Client-Verify SUCCESS;
  proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  proxy_pass https://wssserver1/;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_buffering off;
  proxy_read_timeout 999999999;
}
```

Comment: Should not it be `proxy_pass https://wssserver1/wss/;` and `proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;`?

Comment: Already solved, need to have another location /wss { proxy_pass https://wssserver1/wss }.
 proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade <- $connection_upgrade not working for nginx 1.20 debian

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that it needs `map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
  }`